# mongodb $in operator in $expr doesn't use the index

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I need documents by several identifiers

It doesn't work(freeze):

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $match: {
        $expr: {
            $in: ['$_id', [4, 6]]
        }
    }
}]);
```

but it works:

```
db.collection.find({
    _id: {
        $in: [4, 6]
    }
});
```

Comment: Try this: `{ $match: { _id: {$in: [4, 6]} }`

Comment: Your query with `$expr` _works fine_ too (and returns matching documents). Do post a sample document from your collection.

Comment: your query with `$expr` is working [test here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hcb1DJVRpEO) , maybe you are using old version of MongoDB that doesn't support it?

Comment: @Takis_ Strangely enough, the version corresponds, 5.0.3. Perhaps the difference is that I have a large collection of 2.9m documents, although all the necessary fields are indexed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$expr` has limitation on index use
[see this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/#behavior)

> only $eq, $lt, $lte, $gt, and $gte aggregate operators can use index

In the past even less operators were supported, MongoDB 5.0 added more and probably next versions will add even more.

`$in` aggregate operator cannot use the index.
But if you replace it with

```js
aggregate(
[{"$match":
  {"$expr":{"$or":[{"$eq":[4, "$_id"]}, {"$eq":[6, "$_id"]}]}}}])
```

It will be fast, and index will be used.
Here you can avoid the need for `$expr` you can use the `$in` query operator not the `$in` aggregate operator, as noted in the comments also.

```js
{ $match: { _id: {$in: [4, 6]} }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved me.